# Why do we need typename for type dependent on a template-parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics, typename

I looked up on Wiki for the keyword typename (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typename) and it gives an example which typename is required before T::bar

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{
   // declares a pointer to an object of type T::bar
   T::bar * p;
}

struct StructWithBarAsType {
   typedef int bar;
};

int main() {
   StructWithBarAsType x;
   foo(x);
}
```

Why doesn't C++ inspect StructWithBarAsType and find that T::bar is actually a type when generating code for foo(x)? Is it not possible or just an efficiency consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it assumes that `T::bar` is a static member unless `typename` is specified beforehand.  afaict there is no technical limitation that would prevent compilers from being able to figure out during instantiation whether or not `T::bar` is a type, but to keep things a bit easier for compiler implementors, the decision was made.  It can make more of a difference than than one might think, consider

```
T::bar<a,b>c;
```

is this a variable `c` of type `T::bar<a,b>`, or is it a less than, comma, greater than?  `T::bar < a` followed by `b > c`?  C++ template syntax leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

When parsing a template it may genuinely be impossible to determine whether a type or value is intended. An example is

```
int v = 2;
template <typename T>
void f() {
    T::value * v;
}
```

This code may either declare a pointer or imply an operation. Neither interpretation is particular useful. When the compiler is asked to make sense of this code it doesn't know the type `T`. Now, you could say: have it be prepared for both interpretation! ... but you would have a combinatorial explosion at hand if the next lines carry on with something similar.

I could imagine the compilers could in most cases correctly determine what is meant. However, without further context it is sometimes impossible. At the time `typename` was introduced I also think it was unexpected how often it is needed. To some extend that got fixed by `auto` and `decltype(...)` which get rid of many needs for nested types.